Optimal way to declare a function F to select from a nested set of functions L
I have a set of model equations that i want to group inside a function to call them as required. As an example of desired workflow, it should be as this call:
F(X=t, mode="B")

I have thought over other ways to declare this kind of process:
t <- seq(0,1,.1)
L <- list(
    A = function(x) x^2, 
    B = function(x) x/(x+9), 
    C = function(x) x*exp(x))
F <- L$A(t)
F
 > 0 .01 .04 .09 .016 .025 .036 .049 .064 .081 1

Also, this task could be done with external packages:
t <- seq(0,1,.1)
F <- function(input, mode){
    dplyr::case_when(
        mode == "A" ~ input^2, 
        mode == "B" ~ input/(input+9),
        mode == "C" ~ input*exp(input)
    )
}
F(t, mode="A")
 > 0 .01 .04 .09 .016 .025 .036 .049 .064 .081 1

Thus, in terms of efficiency, is it better to create a reference for this equations inside the global F function and call them as a list or is better to save a external list and load it as a parameter?

If you need to compare efficiency, simply benchmark the two approaches. I expect, benchmarks will show that both approaches are so fast that differences don't matter in practice.

Efficiency will depend on how many functions you have in the list. If it's large (thousands or more) then the lookup time of either approach will probably be measurably slower than using a hash table. It also depends how many times you call each function as R will compile small functions to byte code the second time they're called (by default - you can do this manually or turn it off). But for most practical uses of R, these considerations are unlikely to make a difference, as @Roland says. Better to focus on which approach is more readable and extensible, which in my view is the first one.

The question asks about a matter of efficiency, the answer below is about a convenient way of calling a function from a list of functions.
You can have a function factory return a function that will dynamically select the wanted function from the list and apply it to its argument.
t <- seq(0, 1, 0.1)
L <- list(
  A = function(x) x^2, 
  B = function(x) x/(x+9), 
  C = function(x) x*exp(x))

makeFun <- function(F_List) {
  f <- function(X, mode) F_List[[mode]](X)
  f
}

# create the function with the function factory
f <- makeFun(L)

# see if it works
f(X = t, mode = "A")
#>  [1] 0.00 0.01 0.04 0.09 0.16 0.25 0.36 0.49 0.64 0.81 1.00
f(X = t, mode = "B")
#>  [1] 0.00000000 0.01098901 0.02173913 0.03225806 0.04255319 0.05263158
#>  [7] 0.06250000 0.07216495 0.08163265 0.09090909 0.10000000
f(X = t, mode = "C")
#>  [1] 0.0000000 0.1105171 0.2442806 0.4049576 0.5967299 0.8243606 1.0932713
#>  [8] 1.4096269 1.7804327 2.2136428 2.7182818

Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0
The function factory can be a one-liner, just return 'function(etc)' without assigning the result to 'f'.
makeFun <- function(F_List) function(X, mode) F_List[[mode]](X)

